# Can we remove certificates and create again on Account for iphone app distrbution

Tags: iphone

I have one big problem. I am having iphone developer account and now i have given all the controls to my developer so he has created certificate in account and install it. But he didn't know that if we want to use this information on multi system then we need to keep .p12 certificates and we have to install this certificates on another machine.

We don't have this .p12 certificate and we want to use another machine so what should i do for this things?. How can i delete current certificate from account and create another CSR and certificates for all machine?.

If anyone knows then please drops some line.

Thanks,
iPhone Dev.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have the machine he created the Certificate Signing Requests (CSR) on, then you can export the private key from Keychain Access.  Just find the key and export it.

If the private key is no longer available then you need to revoke the existing certificate and create a new one again.  There are plenty of questions on Stackoverflow about this, e.g.
[Lost Private Key For iPhone Distribution Certificate. What could be solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410156/lost-private-key-for-iphone-distribution-certificate-what-could-be-solutions)