# Lost Private Key For iPhone Distribution Certificate. What could be solutions?

Tags: iphone

I have lost my private key for iPhone Distribution Certificate during an OS upgrade.
Now I want to upload a new iPhone App to the App Store and that requires me to sign the App with an iPhone Distribution Profile/Certificate. Is there any way to create a new iPhone Distribution Certificate. I did not find any "New.." option there on the developer portal.

One more question: must I have to sign the code with an iPhone Distribution Certificate to submit on the App Store? Or can I sign and upload it on the App Store with an iPhone Development certificate?

Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Revoke your current certificate, wait a few seconds and refresh the page and you should see a button "Request Certificate". You'll have to follow the Certificate Signing Request instructions again, and upload the .csr file. You'll then have to wait for your Team Administrator (could well be you) to Accept the new certificate before downloading it and installing in your KeyChain.

You'll have to create a new provisioning profile for the App, using the new certificate.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi adam,
Thanks for your quick helpful reply.
I have also already submitted applications using this iPhone Distribution Certificate. If I revoke the certificate, will be any problem if I want to update the existing applications?

Comment: Not 100% sure on that one, I think you may be able to get away with it, because you will still be using the same App ID. I guess you have no choice anyway, having lost your own one. Would be interested to hear the results.

Please feel free to upvote/accept my answer, if it helped you ;)

Comment: No problem with existing apps if you revoke the cert. I had a client with the same problem as you and we checked with Apple before doing that.

Once you have the new cert, throw away all your provisioning profiles in Xcode and on the Apple site and recreate them because they will all be useless.

Comment: If i revoke the old certificate and upload my app using new certificate and provisioning profile, will i be able to send the push notification on my older version apps ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a solution for this
Revoke certificate you have in distribution and get CSR again (it should be from Mac where you need key) and creat new certificate. Once you do this you will have certificate, now go to profile, you will find profile invalid, edit it and take new certificate you created and regenerate again. Download certificate and profile and use in code and you are good to go