# How do I get a replacement development certificate's p12 file?

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning, pkcs#12

My Mac hard disk crashed, put a new hard disk and reinstalled OS, xcode, but not able to build my app for device target since the certificate does not work any more. I could have used the p12 file but unfortunately I lost it.

So, what's next? How do I update my app which is there in app store? I need to smoke now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lost Private Key For iPhone Distribution Certificate. What could be solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410156/lost-private-key-for-iphone-distribution-certificate-what-could-be-solutions)

Comment: I wish I could give 5 starts for your answer :) Thanks a ton...worked for me, I hope uploading update should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a developer you should know better then to not back up your data. For around $100 you can get all the backup disk size you should need for a development box.

Comment: This is how one of my ex-boss used to help us when we had a situation.