# Distribution certificates for iPhone

Tags: ios, ios4, certificate, provisioning-profile

I have an app at the appstore.
Now I want to switch developers.
If the old developer won't give me the private key for the distribution certificate, what are my options?

- If I revoke my existing distribution certificate and create a new one, I understand that my existing app in the store cannot be updated.
- On the other hand, if I wait until my current distribution certificate expires, then create a new one, then my app at the store should be updatable?

Please whoever can clarify this issue will be blessed!

Comment: Revoke your existing certificate & make new one...

Comment: And then - are there any implications for my app currently at the store?

Comment: no its not affect your existing App....No problem at all...

Comment: So if I want to update my existing app, with then new distribution certificate (end a new distribution  prov. profile) existing users will be able to get it no problem?

Comment: I don't know the answer at the moment, but I do advise that you get a wide variety of answers before you attempt anything drastic. If it turns out you can't update your app after the distro cert has been revoked, you're out of luck.

Comment: Last October, I revoked the previous private key, because the client did have the old one and I could do the update of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be fine with revoking your distribution certificate and making a new one. You can still update an existing app after doing this.

Relevant info:

[Lost Private Key For iPhone Distribution Certificate. What could be solutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410156/lost-private-key-for-iphone-distribution-certificate-what-could-be-solutions)

[If I revoke an existing distribution certificate, will it mess up anything with existing apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320255/if-i-revoke-an-existing-distribution-certificate-will-it-mess-up-anything-with)